# Does the classes on the ul and li menu Change dynamically on Joomla?

Tags: html, css, joomla1.5

Using the joomla 1.5 menu (mainmenu module): Does the classes on the ul and  li menu  Change dynamically on Joomla? or if I make a template based on this classes will it work on all joomla instalations

> anyways I know that is a module that
>   generated "good" classes but since
>   most joomla users are newbies that can
>   be a problem to convince them to install something new...

Answer (score 0):

It certainly appears to: adding `id="current"` and `class="active"` to the selected `li`.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the joomla module.

Add the **`Menu Class Suffix`** of the module.

So this suffix will be added to the joomla default class.

Here is the good guide for joomla class suffix. (e.g mainlevel`yoursuffix`)

[Check Here](http://help.joomla.org/ghop/feb2008/task057/Joomla%20Class%20Suffix%20Guides.pdf)

Its a good practice to use this class suffix in joomla.